# running play 2.3 sub project app in intellij 14 ultimate

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have setup my play 2.3 app inside a sub project (module with in root intellij project).  sbt compile works fine but I cannot figure out how to run the play subproject from with in intellij.  What am I missing?

I have setup my solution folder structure like this (simplified):

- project-root

  - build.sbt
  - webapp (contains activator generated play 2.3 app)

    - app
    - (other play2.3 folders)
    - build.sbt
  - data (contains scala library using slick)

    - src (and standard sub dirs)
    - build.sbt

Here is the root project build.sbt:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.PlayScala

name := "MyApp"

version := "1.0"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.company",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
)

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.1",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.1",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.10",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34"
)

lazy val data = project.in(file("data"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val webapp = project.in(file("webapp"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .enablePlugins(PlayScala, SbtWeb)
    .dependsOn(data)

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(
  webapp,
  data
)
```

and webapp project/plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at         "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```